# How to change volume type when restore volume by backup_id openstack rest api?

Tags: openstack

I create a backup from snapshot_id + volume_id. And that volume_id type is SSD. Then I performed the restore backup operation. Can I change the volume type from SSD to HDD? And at what step is it processed?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of an option to select a different type during restore, but after the restore has succeeded you should be able to [retype](https://docs.openstack.org/cinder/latest/contributor/migration.html) the volume:

```
cinder retype --migration-policy on-demand
              <volume> <volume-type>
Mandatory arguments:
  <volume>              Name or ID of volume for which to modify type.
  <volume-type>         New volume type.
```

Also note the following statement:

> Source volume type and destination volume type must be different and
> they must refer to different back-ends.